# modifying pseudo-xml doc before it hits XmlDocument.Load

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5

I have a series of... pseudo-xml files.  What I mean by this, is they are almost XML files, but they are missing the xml declaration and a root node.  e.g. conceptually it may look like this:

```
<a>info</a>
<b>info2</b>
```

What I want to do is load it into an `XmlDocument` object, e.g something similar to this:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();

    using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(File.Open(@"file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite)))
    {
        xml.Load(file);
    }
```

This is throwing errors, most likely due to the ill formatted pseudo-xml file.  I need to somehow handle adding in a root node before it hits the `Load`.  I don't want to modify the actual file, or have to save anything to disk (e.g. a new temp file).  I'm stuck on this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XmlDocument has also a [LoadXml() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml.aspx) that parses an Xml string. You can load your file content into a string, add the declaration and call LoadXml(). 
Of course, when you are using long files, this can be very memory consuming, pay attention to that.

Comment: `LoadXml` would throw exception for `<a>info</a> <b>info2</b>`

Comment: Cool, I don't know how I missed that.  I'll likely go this route, pondering about the string size/memory issues it might lead to, though.

Comment: @L.B I assume they meant load it as a string, appending the root node a la Romain's example code.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

`var xmlString = file.ReadToEnd();

xmlString = "<root>" + xmlString + "</root>";

xml.LoadXml(xmlString);`